# Kind compiler plugin λ not found

Tags: scala, type-kinds, kind-projector

I have enabled the kind compiler plugin `addCompilerPlugin("org.spire-math" % "kind-projector" % "0.9.6")` and I can now use the `?` symbol e.g. `Map[String, ?]` however Lambda and λ are not resolved.

`val f: Id ~> Future = λ[Id ~> Future](...)`

produces `Error: not found: value λ`. Is λ still supported by the kind compiler?

Comment: Are you compiling with sbt, or some kind of editor (like IntelliJ)? E.g. IntelliJ has written their own scala parser and might give you false flags.

Comment: I get the same error in intellij and normal sbt:compile

Answer (score 4):

Firstly, just a reminder that one should add

```
addCompilerPlugin("org.spire-math" %% "kind-projector" % "0.9.6")
```

to `build.sbt` and not for example to `plugins.sbt`.

Then, for example, for

```
import scala.language.higherKinds

trait MyTrait[F[_]]
```

declaration with type lambda

```
class MyClass extends MyTrait[({ type l[A] = Map[String, A] })#l]
```

can be replaced with

```
class MyClass extends MyTrait[Map[String, ?]]
```

or

```
class MyClass extends MyTrait[λ[A => Map[String, A]]]
```

or

```
class MyClass extends MyTrait[Lambda[A => Map[String, A]]]
```

I'm not sure if

```
val f: Id ~> Future = λ[Id ~> Future](???)
```

is a valid syntax.

`~>` is usually used for natural transformations like in

```
import cats.{Id, ~>}
import scala.concurrent.Future
import scala.concurrent.ExecutionContext.Implicits.global

val f: Id ~> Future = new (Id ~> Future) {
  override def apply[A](fa: A): Future[A] = Future(fa)
}
```

and not for type lambdas.

Update. Ok, it's polymorphic lambda https://github.com/typelevel/kind-projector#polymorphic-lambda-values

Answer (score 0):

I've just solved this exact problem (and not for the first time, it feels) by doing a quick `rm -rf ./target` and restarting everything.

I also deleted my ensime project cache, just to make sure - presumably doing the same for IntelliJ would be a good idea too.